# replacing shapefile data source in subdirectories with feature class

Tags: arcpy

I have lots of mxds in subdirectories of this folder. I would like to walk through them and replace a shapefile with a feature class from a geodatabase with something like this. This code here is not working. I'm not sure how to incorporate the feature class in this.

```
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
ws = r"C:\Users\test\Desktop\New_folder"
oldpath = r"\\test\newfolder\oldfile.shp"
newpath = r"\\test\newfolder\newdatabase.gdb"
newfeatureclass = r"\\test\newfolder\newdatabase.gdb\feature"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(ws):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.mxd'):
            fullpath = os.path.join(root, f)
            mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(fullpath)
            print "Replacing path for " + f +"..."
            mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(oldpath, newpath + newfeatureclass)
            mxd.save()
            del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenate `newpath` and `newfeatureclass` with `os.path.join()`:

```
...
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(oldpath, os.path.join(newpath, newfeatureclass))
...
```